# OSX Bootcamp Windows 10: Can't click in-app button while holding down key

Tags: macos, windows-10, mouse, boot-camp

Self-explanatory. The catch is that even when I release the key, I need to click twice for the button for some reason. I notice this issue stops happening with a USB mouse, but why? How can I fix this trackpad issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the palm detection preventing you from unwanted mouse movements / clicks when hitting the touchpad with your hand while typing. Windows disables the touchpad while you're pressing keys on the keyboard, even a few milliseconds after the last keystroke. Therefore, you have to wait (or click twice), even after typing.

Probably you didn't install the right bootcamp drivers. Get them using the bootcamp utility on Mac OS, or from the [Apple Support download page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/boot%2520camp), e.g. [Version 5769](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) at the present time, and make sure to install the trackpad driver.

Comment: Could depend on which Mac it is as to whether support even exists for Win10.